# Download button for multiple files in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a Shiny application and I am trying to add a download button to download csv files (tables taken from a database). Basically I have a checkboxgroupInput with 4 values, every value corresponds to a different table and the button should download the tables that are "ticked" is a single zip file

I have tried different versions of my code, even if it does not throw any errors, when I run the application, when the download button is clicked it tries to download an inexistent files. I think that the for is never executed, but I don't understand why. So my idea was to populate selectedCountry with the ifelse and then write everyelement as csv and the create the ziip with the csv. I have tried to download the single table, so ITALY_DB etc are not empty or null, they work properly.

```
server.R
Italy_tbl <- data.frame(ITALY_DB())
ne_tbl <- data.frame(NE_DB())
turkey_tbl <- data.frame(TURKEY_DB())
usa_tbl <- data.frame(USA_DB())
selectedCountry<- vector()

observeEvent(input$country,{
  ifelse (input$country == "Italy",selectedCountry <- 
  C(selectedCountry,Italy_tbl), selectedCountry<-selectedCountry)

  ifelse (input$country == "Turkey",selectedCountry <- 
  C(selectedCountry,turkey_tbl),selectedCountry<-selectedCountry)

  ifelse (input$country == "Netherlands",selectedCountry <-
  C(selectedCountry,ne_tbl ),selectedCountry<-selectedCountry)

  ifelse (input$country == "USA",selectedCountry <- 
  C(selectedCountry,usa_tbl),selectedCountry<-selectedCountry)

  })

output$download <- downloadHandler(


filename = function() {
  paste0(input$country,".zip")

  #paste(input$country, ".csv", sep = "")
},


content = function(file) {


  #go to a temp dir to avoid permission issues
  owd <- setwd(tempdir())
  print(tempdir())
  on.exit(setwd(owd))
  files <- NULL;

  for(i in selectedCountry){

    fileName <- paste(input$country,"_0",".csv",sep = "")
    write.csv(selectedCountry[i],fileName,sep = ';', row.names = F, 
    col.names = T)
    files <- c(fileName,files)


    }
   zip(file,files)


  }
)




  ui.R

  column(3,inputPanel( 
  sliderInput('yearSlider', 'Select Years', sep="",
  min=2009, max=2018, step=1, value =c(2009,2018)),


  (checkboxGroupInput("country",h4('Select Countries'),
  choices = list("Italy" = 1,
                 "Netherlands" = 2,                                                                   
                 "Turkey" = 3,
                 "USA" = 4),
                selected = 1)),
  radioButtons(
               inputId = 'plotCount'
               , label   = 'Plot Count'
               , choices = as.character(1:2)
               , inline=T
                ),
               downloadButton("download", "Download Data")
     ))
```

I am sure there is something I am missing, but I just don't understand what

Comment: I cannot imagine a situation where assignment inside `ifelse` (single or nested) makes sense to me (inside your `observeEvent(input$country` block. In this example, it might be better to do `selectedCountry <- switch(input$country, Italy = Italy_tbl, Turkey = turkey_tbl, Netherlands = ne_tbl, USA = usa_tbl)`. Further, because it's in an `observeEvent` and it makes no changes to reactive objects, that block is a complete no-op. Might you mean to use `<<-` to append the table into the outer-placed vector?

Comment: Further, because of the inferred assignment from an `observeEvent` block, if a user toggles between Italy and Turkey and Italy and Turkey and Italy and Turkey ... the parent-env `selectedCountry` will now have six frames in it, three of each. Is this intentional? (Am I misinterpreting things?)

Comment: @r2evans you're completely right, but my intention was to have some zip download, no matter if with duplicate, I would have solved that later. Until now it just downloads a fake file without a proper extension and I don't get why it cannot build the zip file

Comment: It is like the code is not even executed since if i put a print inside the loop it does not show on the console

Comment: Sorry, you're right. One typo I can see  right  off is that in  your `ifelse` blocks you try to concatenate with capital `C`, rather  than lower  case `c`. Also, there's no need for that whole block, since accessing a `checkboxGroupInput` gives a vector of all selected options. You could  just put your data frames in a list and subset with `input$country`